# Calculating how many times 'ng-repeat' has looped, then export as a string/value in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently trying to build a 'like' function in to my Angular.js app. I have the basic 'like' section, with the following code:

```
$scope.likeClicked = function () {

      if (!hasLiked) {
          hasLiked = true;
          $scope.liked = 'Unlike';
          $scope.likeCount += 1;
      } else {
          hasLiked = false;
          $scope.liked = 'Like';
          $scope.likeCount -= 1;          
      }

  };
```

What I want to achieve, and because the 'likes will be provided from a JSON file that then loops with 'ng-repeat', is a function that calculates how many likes there are in the JSON file. Just to note, the JSON file we are being provided with doesn't explicitly state the 'likes' numerically, you only know by them having a 'name' object in the file.

Please help, I have never used JSON before!

Thanks.

JP

Comment: Sample JSON would help.  Depending on the structure, it should be as referencing an array's `length` property in your HTML like: `{{username}} likes {{jsonDataOfThingsThisUserLikes.length}} things`

Comment: If you're parsing the JSON file, I'm not sure ng-repeat is what you want as that directive is normally used for repeating DOM elements. I'd probably hand the JSON to a controller that parsed out the "Likes" into a more usable structure and put that into $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to get that answer out of `ng-repeat`. That's sorta backwards - why would you do a DOM lookup to get a piece of information that's already available on the scope? You probably want something like this:

```
$http.get('likes.json').success(function(data) {

  $scope.likes = data;

});

$scope.addLike = function(item) {
    // add item to $scope.likes
}
```

Then in your html do you can something like:

```
<p>You have liked {{likes.length}} items.</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item}}
        <button ng-click="addLike(item)"></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Rosarch. I should have thought to use .length!